# The enthalpy of two gas mixture

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is $\Delta H_{mix}=0$ in a mixture of ideal gases? If $\Delta H=\Delta U + \Delta PV $ and I know that in ideal gases there are no interactions between molecules so $\Delta Q=0$

How do I prove this? Do the gases need to have constant pressure so $\Delta H_{mix}=Q$? If not, I really don't understand how could it be $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Are you talking about having two gases in separate boxes of volumes $V_1$ and $V_2$, both at pressure $P$?, and then you connect the boxes?

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes, that's exactly my question, would it change something if the two gases had different pressure?

Comment: It is easy for the same $P$ in both boxes. The pressure before and after is $P$. The volume before and after is $V_1 + V_2$. You should think about how you would figure it out if the different boxes have different $P$'s. That is a homework problem we can't answer on this site.

Comment: It's not a homework problem, I just don't understand why $\Delta H_{mix}=0$ even when pressure is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof requires statistical mechanics, but we can give a qualitative explanation.

First, we are referring to mixing under constant temperature and constant pressure, that's how $\Delta H_\text{mix}$ is defined. In the ideal gas state there are no interactions so the energy ($U$) is the energy of the individual molecules, translational plus any intermolecular forms, e.g., rotation, vibration etc. So when we mix two different ideal gases at same temperature their total energy is the sum of the individual energies, i.e.,
$$\Delta U_\text{mix} = 0$$
And since there are no interactions, there is no volume change. Volume would contract or expand upon mixing of molecules of different kinds are preferentially attracted or repelled. In the absence of interactions none of this happens, so
$$\Delta V_\text{mix} = 0$$
For the enthalpy of mixing we have
$$\Delta H_\text{mix} = \Delta (U+PV)_\text{mix}
= \Delta U_\text{mix} + P \Delta V_\text{mix} = 0
$$
Notice that $P$ comes out of $\Delta(PV)_\text{mix}$ because as we said all properties of mixing are defined under the conditions that the pure gases and the mixture are at the same $T$ and $P$.